# Generate error when user tries to access non-existent path

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

I have developed a website which contains a few pages, for example:

```
http://localhost:32080/PlanSummary.aspx
```

However, when I type `/djwfjafjd` or any random character or string after the aspx page, I can still access the website normally without any 404 error. (Browser still displays `PlanSummary.aspx` page) But it should display an error like 404 that this page does not exist.

```
http://localhost:32080/PlanSummary.aspx/djwfjafjd
```

At this point, if I click on other link on the page, for example, `ProductionPlan.aspx` it will navigate to `http://localhost:32080/PlanSummary.aspx/ProductionPlan.aspx` but browser still displays `PlanSummary.aspx` page.

I earlier believed that this has something to do with error handling, which I currently using `httpErrors` to handle 404 and 500 errors and it works perfectly. I tested it by accessing `http://localhost:32080/PlanSummaryxxxxxx.aspx` and it redirected me to "friendly" not found website that I created.

Right now I really don't know what is the cause of this problem. Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Comment: I think it should have something to do with routing in web forms. I'd check this article on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx and see if there is something...

Comment: First of all, your link is broken it it calls your URL like this. Second this is complete normal behavior. The resolved URL routes to the first valid Path and interprets everything else as Parameter. In your case  `http://localhost:32080/PlanSummary.aspx/` is the route and `ProductionPlan.aspx` the parameter.

Comment: Ensure you are using "~" links to prevent navigation issues, e.g.: `<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="~/ProductionPlan.aspx">
    Production Plan
</asp:HyperLink>` else the paths could be misinterpreted by the browser